# Openerp payslip with leave in salary rule with python code

Tags: python, openerp-7

I have to calculate payslip with medical leave for 3 conditions.

E.g.:

```
result = worked_days.Medical and worked_days.Medical.number_of_days or False
if(result>25):result=contract.wage-10000
elif(result<25 and result>10):reuslt=contract.wage-20000
else:result=30000`
```

Comment: Please elaborate your problem?

Comment: I want to make condition in python code for my 3 conditions.

Comment: if (no_of_medical_leave_days>25):result=100000;elif(no_of_medical_leave_days<25 and no_of_medical_leave_days>10):result=20000;else:result=30000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, I coded in air. Hope this help.

Create a code for Medical as `WORK100` has and than you can access in salary rules. like `worked_days.Medical.no_of_medical_leave_days` otherwise it's give error like `Wrong python code.`

```
    <record id="hr_rule_medical_days" model="hr.salary.rule">
        <field name="name">Medical Leave Days</field>
        <field name="sequence" eval="1"/>
        <field name="code">MEDICAL</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="hr_payroll.DED"/>
        <field name="condition_select">none</field>
        <field name="amount_select">code</field>
        <field name="amount_python_compute">result = 0
days = worked_days.Medical.no_of_medical_leave_days
if days>25:
    result=100000;
elif(days<25 and days>10):
    result=20000;
else:
    result=30000</field>
    </record>
```

And additionally add  **id**  of above `hr_rule_medical_days` to with `Salary Structure`

Comment: I want to test condition in Python Code of salary rule medical leave.

Comment: Thanks You Very Much.Your answer is well woking.Great!...Thanks Odedra.

Comment: Hi ..I want total number of leaves from leave summary.And then I want to use in salary rule .What should I do?

Comment: I think it's not possible with it. We can calculate based on Number of days or Number of Hours.